# ASP.NET Core MVC: asp-for is rendering incomplete id and name attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When I iterate over a list in my .cshtml file, for some reason the id and name attribute values are rendered incomplete. For example:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.product.ProductDetail.Count(); i++)
{
    <input type="text"
    asp-for="product.ProductDetail.ElementAt(i).Sku"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="@SharedLocalizer["Sku"]" />
}
```

Is rendered as:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Sku" id="Sku" name="Sku">
```

Instead of:

```
<input type="text" id="product.ProductDetail_0__Sku" name="product.ProductDetail[0].Sku" class="form-control" placeholder="Sku">
```

I am using Entity Framework Core 3.1.3, here is my model:

Product:

```
public partial class Product
{
     public Product()
     {
          ProductDetail = new HashSet<ProductDetail>();
     }

     /* More properties here... */

     public virtual ICollection<ProductDetail> ProductDetail { get; set; }
}
```

ProductDetail:

```
public partial class ProductDetail
{
    /* More properties here... */
    public string Sku { get; set; }
}
```

ProductViewModel:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public Product product { get; set; }
    /* More properties here... */
}
```

Do you know why is this happening?

Comment: Can you share your model class please?

Comment: @CalC sure, I have updated the question with the model. Thank you.

Comment: When I try to replicate the problem using an `ICollection` I get an error 'cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `ICollection<..>`'. Are you sure you are using an `IColleciton` for `ProductDetail`? If so, how are you indexing it in the tag helper? You may be better off using a List<> in a view model instead of an `ICollection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, using `asp-for="product.ProductDetail[i].Sku"` as CalC shared could work for me with testing model data.

If it indeed doesn’t work for you, you can try to manually set id, name and value attributes for your input fields, like below.

Here is my code of Model:

products:

```
public class Products
{
    public Product product { get; set; }
}
```

Product:

```
public class Product
{
    public List<ProductDetail> ProductDetail { get; set; }
}
```

ProductDetail:

```
public class ProductDetail
{
    public string Sku { get; set; }
}
```

view:

```
<div>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.product.ProductDetail.Count(); i++)
    {
        <input type="text"
               asp-for="product.ProductDetail[i].Sku"
               class="form-control" 
               placeholder="@SharedLocalizer["Sku"]"/>
    }
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.product.ProductDetail.Count(); i++)
    {
        <input type="text"
               id="product_ProductDetail_@(i)__Sku"
               name="product.ProductDetail[@(i)].Sku"
               value="@Model.product.ProductDetail.ElementAt(i).Sku"
               class="form-control"
               placeholder="@SharedLocalizer["Sku"]"/>
    }
</div>
```

And this is the result:
[image]

Comment: For some strange reason `asp-for="product.ProductDetail[i].Sku"` doesn't work for me, but I manually set the id and name as you mentioned.

Comment: `I manually set the id and name as you mentioned` Do you mean that the above workaround works for you?

Answer (score 1):

The `asp-for` is a `ModelExpression` that is evaluated in order to build up the `id` and `name` attributes. If you use `ElementAt()`, this expression cannot be evaluated fully.

Try using a direct indexer int your collection instead. Example as follows:

```razor
<input type="text"
asp-for="product.ProductDetail[i].Sku"
class="form-control"
placeholder="@SharedLocalizer["Sku"]" />
```

**Edit:**
I strongly recommend using view models rather than data persistence level models with your views. You could then use a `List` in your view model (instead of an `ICollection` and apply the above indexing accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I made the changes you suggested, but the HTML generated is as follows: `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="z0__Sku" name="[0].Sku" placeholder="Sku">`

Comment: It should be `asp-for="product.ProductDetail[i].Sku"`

Comment: I did noted the typo, so I tried `asp-for="product.ProductDetail[i].Sku"`, but I get `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="z0__Sku" name="[0].Sku" placeholder="Sku">` instead of `<input type="text" id="product.ProductDetail_0__Sku" name="product.ProductDetail[0].Sku" class="form-control" placeholder="Sku">`